# How to figure out 500 error in uwsgi environment

Tags: django, uwsgi

Application deploy by uwsgi+django+nginx, each time has about 300 request, but uwsgi will generate random 500 error, I check django log no issue find, uwsgi print log as following:

```
generated 47 bytes in 9 msecs (HTTP/1.0 500) 1 headers in 70 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
```

Is there any solution to figure out the reason of 500 about uwsgi?

Since 500 generate by uwsgi, so it is not the issue between nginx and uwsgi.

Comment: Which version of python are you using? There is a bug in memory management if you use python2.5 with django/wsgi which generated random 500 errors :P

Answer (score 0):

Your uWSGI logs should reveal more about the issue.  For starters, the logs should reveal what the request URI was for the requests that errored:

```
[pid: 29526|app: 0|req: 1/1] 127.0.0.1 () {28 vars in 297 bytes} [Mon Apr 21 00:11:46 2014] GET /example => generated 4 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 0 headers in 0 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
```

In this case, it was a request to `/example`.  This may reveal a pattern as to what is causing the error.  Separately, if the error is caused by Python somewhere, then uncaught tracebacks will be recorded (via stderr) in the same fashion.

To simplify debugging the issue, you may want to consider running uWSGI using just its in-built HTTP router (via `uwsgi --http :8080 ...`) and making direct requests to that.

Answer (score 0):

uwsgi should forward stdout from workers. One might want to look into django logging to make it output details about exceptions/errors happening there